# Newline break python

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll6RS.png)

i keep getting this error in my code.

```
class Plant:
   def __init__(self,name,cost):
       self.name =name
       self.cost =cost
   
   def print_info(self):
       print("   Plant name:",self.name)
       print("   Cost:",self.cost)

class Flower(Plant):
   def __init__(self,name,cost,annual,color):
       Plant.__init__(self,name,cost)
       self.annual =annual
       self.color =color
   def print_info(self):
       print("   Plant name:",self.name)
       print("   Cost:",self.cost) 
       print("   Annual:",self.annual)
       print("   Color of flowers:",self.color) 

def print_list(plants):
   for i,plant in enumerate(plants):
       print("Plant",i+1,"Information:")
       plant.print_info()
       print("\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   my_garden=[]
   while True:
     line = input().strip().split()
     if line[0]=="-1":
       break
     if line[0]=="plant":
       my_garden.append(Plant(line[1],int(line[2])))
     elif line[0]=="flower":
       my_garden.append(Flower(line[1],int(line[2]),line[3],line[4]))
print()
print_list(my_garden)
```

I KEEP GETTING THIS ERROR

Comment: Please copy the code instead of uploading an image.

Comment: YOU KEEP GETTING *WHAT* ERROR?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest it is the fault of your empty `print`, which adds an extra (unwanted) blank line.

Comment: I still get the same error.